# Issue with FlowListView Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using FlowListView To set gallery view in my xamarin forms application, with following code..

```
 public class Page1 : ContentPage
    {

        public Page1()
        {
            ObservableCollection<ItemModel> List = new ObservableCollection<ItemModel>();
            string[] images = {
                "https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8625/15806486058_7005d77438.jpg",
                "https://farm5.staticflickr.com/4011/4308181244_5ac3f8239b.jpg",
                "https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7423/8729135907_79599de8d8.jpg",
                "https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2475/4058009019_ecf305f546.jpg",
                "https://farm6.staticflickr.com/5117/14045101350_113edbe20b.jpg",
                "https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1227/1116750115_b66dc3830e.jpg",
                "https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7351/16355627795_204bf423e9.jpg",
                "https://farm1.staticflickr.com/44/117598011_250aa8ffb1.jpg",
                "https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7524/15620725287_3357e9db03.jpg",
                "https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8351/8299022203_de0cb894b0.jpg",
            };

            int number = 0;
            for (int n = 0; n < 20; n++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < images.Length; i++)
                {
                    number++;
                    var item = new ItemModel()
                    {
                        ImageUrl = images[i],
                        FileName = string.Format("image_{0}.jpg", number),
                    };

                    List.Add(item);
                }
            }

            FlowListView listView = new FlowListView()
            {
                FlowColumnTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(ListCell)),
                SeparatorVisibility = SeparatorVisibility.None,
                HasUnevenRows = true,
                FlowColumnMinWidth = 110,
                FlowItemsSource = List,
            };
            listView.FlowItemTapped += (s, e) =>
            {
                var item = (ItemModel)e.Item;
                if (item != null)
                {
                    App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Alert", "Tapped {0} =" + item.FileName, "Cancel");
                }
            };

            Content = new StackLayout
            {
                Children = {
                   listView
                }
            };
        }
    }
    public class ItemModel
    {
        public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
        public string FileName { get; set; }

    }
    public class ListCell : View
    {
        public ListCell()
        {
            CachedImage IconImage = new CachedImage
            {
                HeightRequest = 100,
                Aspect = Aspect.Fill,
                DownsampleHeight = 100,
                DownsampleUseDipUnits = false,
                LoadingPlaceholder = "image_loading.png",
                ErrorPlaceholder = "image_error.png"
            };
            IconImage.SetBinding(CachedImage.SourceProperty, "ImageUrl");

            Label NameLabel = new Label
            {
                Opacity = 0.5,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill,
                HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.End,
            };
            NameLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "FileName");
            Grid grd = new Grid
            {
                Padding = 3,
                ColumnDefinitions = {
                    new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength (1, GridUnitType.Star) },
                },
                RowDefinitions = {
                    new RowDefinition { Height=GridLength.Star},
                },
            };
            grd.Children.Add(IconImage,0,0);
            grd.Children.Add(NameLabel, 0, 1);
        }
    }
```

i added all the dependency of FlowListView, FFImage etc,

This above code just showing blank screen, Not displaying any data...

Comment: Please provide code for FlowListView and CachedImage to reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

You're ListCell has nothing to show.

Append the existing lines to set the content to the grid in your custom ViewCell.

```
grd.Children.Add(IconImage,0,0);   
grd.Children.Add(NameLabel, 0, 1);
Content = grd;   <--- add this line
```

Also have you done the following as per advice from the author? i.e. You've added the nuget library to the platforms in addition to the PCL and added the corresponding initialisation code for the library?

> You must add this line to your platform specific project (AppDelegate.cs, MainActivity.cs, etc) before you use FFImageLoading:

```
CachedImageRenderer.Init();
```

This is what I got in my IOS:

```
[Register("AppDelegate")]
public partial class AppDelegate : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate
{
    public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();

        FFImageLoading.Forms.Touch.CachedImageRenderer.Init();  <---- this line

        LoadApplication(new App());

        return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
    }
}
```